# Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/ram/login.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php

When i am running my `index.php` i am getting two error:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required
>   'C:/wamp/www/ram/login.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown
>   on line 0

login.php:

```
    session_start();
    require_once    './config.php';

    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($_POST['user']));
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($_POST['pass']));

        $que="select * from tbl_admin where UserId = '$user_id' AND Password= '$password' AND Status = 1 ";
        $result = $con->query($que);

        if($result->num_rows>0){

                 $row=$result->fetch_assoc();

                    $_SESSION['UserName'] = $row['Name'];
                    $_SESSION['UserId'] = $row['UserId'];

                    header('Location:index.php');

                    }

    else{$err = "Username Or Password is Wrong"; }              

    }
```

index.php:

```
require_once    'config.php';

    session_start();

if($_SESSION['UserId']=="" || $_SESSION['UserId']==NULL)
{
    header('Location:login.php');
}
else if($_SESSION['UserName']=="" || $_SESSION['UserName']==NULL)
{
    header('Location:login.php');
}
```

can any one help me how to solve it.

Comment: Yes you have to show the code of the file where you get these errors.then only we can help .btw the problem is path of the file `login.php` is not correct.

Comment: @ Alive to Die see login.php

Comment: Add index.php coding also. Because you have error there

Comment: @Alive to Die added index.php